# TYPO3 date issue

Tags: php, typo3

I'm a new user of TYPO3 and I'm creating a simple extension for registering data in backend and for display them.

I have two date fields with which we can choose dates ourselves to determine the duration of an event by example startDate and endDate

However, when I display the elements saved thanks to my extension, it does not display the date on the date entered, but on today's date.

In database, the date is recorded in UNIX format but with the right values, for example I entered this date: 21-01-2022 and it records 1642806000 in database

I don't know why I have this problem, you think it is a configuration problem?

Here is some snippet of code:

TCA

```
 'start_date' => [
            'label' => 'start date',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
                'eval' => 'date, int',
                ],
        ],
        'end_date' => [
            'label' => 'end date',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
                'eval' => 'date, int',
            ],
        ],
```

SQL

```
start_date int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
end_date int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
```

Model

```
protected $startdate = '';

protected $enddate = '';

    /**
    * @return \DateTime
    */
   public function getStartdate()
   {
       return $this->Startdate;
   }

   /**
    * @param \DateTime $startdate
    */
   public function setStartdate($startdate)
   {
       $this->startdate = $startdate;
   }


   /**
    * @return \DateTime
    */
   public function getEnddate()
   {
       return $this->enddate;
   }

   /**
    * @param \DateTime $enddate
    */
   public function setEnddate($enddate)
   {
       $this->enddate = $enddate;
   }
```

HTML

```
<f:format.date format="d.m.Y">{event.start_date}</f:format.date>
```

Thanks you for your help

i'm using TYPO3 10.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use underscores in SQL, therefor the mapping is not working.
Extbase expects a SQL field named `start_date` when you use `startDate` in your model.

It's quite hidden in the Extbase Docs, but I found it (and will change it to be more prominent):
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/main/en-us/6-Persistence/1-prepare-the-database.html#preparing-the-tables-of-the-domain-objects

Comment: I changed startDate to start_date, and unfortunately I still see today's date displayed instead of the date entered

Comment: Did you change it in TCA definition as well?

Comment: yes I remplaced "startDate" by "start_date" in TCA too

Comment: You re-saved your record as its stored in another field now? Cleared cache?

Comment: Yes, I created a new content, I clean the cache everytime and the issue still persist

Comment: Can you repost your code? SQL, TCA and model?

Comment: yes, I edited my question with new SQL TCA Model

Comment: The model needs to stay with `startDate`. It maps it automatically from `start_date => startDate`. See the documentation link.

Comment: It still doesn't work, when i try to debug, theses variables are NULL

Comment: Can you edit your post again?

Comment: I did it, I edited only the model

Comment: You didn't get it. `start_date` will be mapped to `startDate` with a capital `D`. In your model you have a `d`. Read the documentation carefully.

Comment: Ok I understood my mistake, I modified and it works correctly thank you!